# How can I get the Current Date in a Cognos query expression?

Tags: cognos

I have a query expression in Cognos where I need to compare a past date to the current date. I don't see one in the functions list and I'm otherwise unsure how to put the query date inside a query object.

How can I use the current date in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your Database software, the object will be either be `current_date` (SQL Server) or `SYSDATE{}` (Oracle). If you don't know which you have, just make an expression of just the function and press the Validate button; if you get an error, you used the wrong function for your database.

You can then use this object like any other Date query object, so you can add/compare it to dates in your query or display it somewhere on the page.

Comment: There is also a 'date' constant, but that is a Cognos application constant, so the filter will be applied after the query is pulled from the database, so use with caution.  Using your Database-specific date function is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `current_date`. This method is data source agnostic and will be converted to the appropriate data source equivalent at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this with your query:

SELECT 
FIELD1
FROM TABLE
WHERE
FIELD2 = current_date

Asumming that FIELD2 has a date format