# Getting the current date using a relational table

Tags: mdx, prompt, cognos, cognos-10

I have two prompts and each prompt allows you to select a number day. If I select 1 and 18 it will give me all of the days from the 1st-18th. Right now the prompts default to the 1st and 2nd. I need the second prompt to default to the current day and I am not quite sure how to do that using a relational table. I know how to do it in a cube but I am not using that for this report. I am using Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the Current Date in a Cognos query expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712125/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-in-a-cognos-query-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Setting dynamic defaults with a relational source in Cognos is difficult. You could use JavaScript. I have a [tutorial](http://cogblogger.com/2015/02/javascript-setting-prompt-defaults-dynamically/) on my blog that shows how to do that using the Cognos 10.2+ JavaScript API that can be adapted for your use:

[Javascript: Setting Prompt Defaults Dynamically](http://cogblogger.com/2015/02/javascript-setting-prompt-defaults-dynamically/)